# What are Batman's qualifications?

Tags: dc, batman

I think it's safe to say that Bruce Wayne (being the secret identity of Batman) is a master in numerous skills and abilities, just to name a few:

- Martial Arts
- Intelligence
- Stealth & disguise
- Scientific/technological know-how
  etc.

Brilliant stuff. But is he actually certified in anything? Did he go to college/university and graduate?

Comment: I think you mean to ask if he's *certified* in anything. He's obviously *qualified* in many areas, as he can perform the necessary tasks just fine.

Comment: Urgh. So many different back-stories. A cursory search on google reveals that he went to Yale and got a degree in Law, went to Princeton, then dropped out, never went to university/attended one course at Gotham University and found it so elementary that he didn't bother going back, etc etc etc.

Comment: Do you mean "professional" qualifications, i.e. as a doctor, engineer, lawyer or other professional occupation that comes with a degree?

Comment: @Richard And in the Dark Knight Saga, he went to ninja school, but he didn't like the final exam, so he quit and tried to get the principal fired.

Comment: @user35594 - Would you like some more examples or is my answer sufficient?

Comment: @phantom42 thank you, yes I meant _certified_, poor word choice on my part.

Comment: @Thaddeus yes I did mean "professional" qualification, as per my previous comment, my word choice has been poor =)

Comment: What makes him any different, you ask? He's not the one wearing hockey pads.

Comment: @Omegacron - No, he's just wearing hockey pads covered in titanium :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Batman has about eighteen different back-stories so I'll just focus on a couple.

In the comic series "**[Night of the Stalker](http://www.comicvine.com/detective-comics-439-night-of-the-stalker/4000-112712/)**" (originally appearing in 1974 in Detective Comics #439, we see that he has a diploma on his wall. Closer inspection reveals it to be from [Yale University of Law](http://web.archive.org/web/20110313101425/http://www.yalealumnimagazine.com/issues/2011_03/batman326.html).

[image]

In [Batman #93](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_93) (in a segment called "Batman's College Days") we learn that he has a degree in Criminology from Gotham University

[image]

And in [Batman Begins](http://www.raindance.org/site/picture/upload/image/general/movies/batman_begins.pdf), we see that young Bruce is on the verge of dropping out of Princeton University:

> **ALFRED :** *Will you be heading back to Princeton tomorrow or could I persuade you to spend an extra night or two?*
>
> **BRUCE :** *I’m not heading back at all.*
>
> **ALFRED :** *You don’t like it there?*
>
> Bruce smiles, sardonic. Looks out at the trees flashing by.
>
> **BRUCE :** *I like it fine... they just don’t feel the same way.*

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the answer. _Note to self: do research on back-stories, multiple universes, resurrections..._ =)

Comment: @user35594 - You're in for a masochistic treat.